# How to test View Model coroutines that blocks the thread before assertions?

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines, android-testing, android-viewmodel

I'm trying to write a test for a View Model. I'm doing an instrumented test since I need `context`.

The view model and test looks like:

```
    class MyViewModel(
private val dispatcher: CoroutineDispatchers = Dispatchers.IO) : ViewModel() {
        private val _livedata = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
        val livedata: LiveData<Boolean> = _livedata

    fun doSomething() {
        viewModelScope.launch(dispatcher) {
            //suspend function with retrofit
            _livedata.value = true
        }
    }
}

class MyViewModelTest {
    private lateinit var viewModel: MyViewModel

   @get:Rule
   var mainCoroutineRule = MainCoroutineRule()

   @get:Rule
   var instantTaskExecutorRule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()

    @Before
    fun setup() {
        viewModel = MyViewModel(mainCoroutineRule.dispatcher)
    }

    @Test
    fun testMyViewModel() {
        mainCoroutineRule.runBlockingTest {
            viewModel.doSomething()

            mainCoroutineRule.dispatcher.advanceUntilIdle()

            val result = viewModel.livedata.getOrAwaitValue()

            assertThat(result).isTrue()
        }
    }
}
```

The issue is how `result` is null due to `doSomething()` being called on another coroutine and is done asynchronously.

How can I run my test so that the suspend function blocks the thread so my assertion captures the `result` after the suspend function is finished?

I'm pretty confused from the information out there.

I don't think I need `InstantTaskExecutorRule()` because I'm doing an instrumented test?

Adding this rule doesn't help:

```
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
class MainCoroutineRule(val dispatcher: TestCoroutineDispatcher = TestCoroutineDispatcher()):
   TestWatcher(),
   TestCoroutineScope by TestCoroutineScope(dispatcher) {
   override fun starting(description: Description?) {
       super.starting(description)
       Dispatchers.setMain(dispatcher)
   }

   override fun finished(description: Description?) {
       super.finished(description)
       cleanupTestCoroutines()
       Dispatchers.resetMain()
   }
}
```

Do I need to inject a coroutine dispatcher in my view model that blocks the main thread?

Comment: Did you actually try `InstantTaskExecutorRule`?
Did you actually add an instance of `MainCoroutineRule` or did you just declare it as shown in your question? Post the full example.

Comment: I've updated the post with what I have so far. The suspend function is calling a retrofit api call, with no other switches in context/dispatchers. Then it eventually calls `postValue` on the live data.

Comment: I'd try adding logs through out and printing out the current coroutine / thread values to see what's in what order.

Comment: I'm finding when I'm logging the thread name in my functions, it all uses `Instr: androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner`. Would this be the right thread to use?

Answer (score 0):

If you're launching a coroutine to call a Retrofit service, you probably want to do that on the IO dispatcher. You could pass that in as a dependency, then pass a test one in the test to control it.

```
class MyViewModel : ViewModel(private val ioDispatcher: Dispatcher = Dispatchers.IO) {
    private val _livedata = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
    val livedata: LiveData<Boolean> = _livedata

    fun doSomething() {
        viewModelScope.launch(ioDispatcher) {
            //suspend function with retrofit
            _livedata.value = true
        }
    }
}
```

Test:

```
@Before
fun setup() {
    viewModel = MyViewModel(coroutineRule.dispatcher)
}

@Test
fun testMyViewModel() {
    mainCoroutineRule.runBlockingTest {
        viewModel.doSomething()

        coroutineRule.dispatcher.advanceUntilIdle()

        val result = viewModel.livedata.value

        assertThat(result).isTrue()
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work. `runBlockingTest` won't work either. I think it only works if `doSomething()` was a suspend function itself.

Comment: I posted another suggestion.

Comment: I found `getOrAwait` in this article to resolve the problem https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/unit-testing-livedata-and-other-common-observability-problems-bb477262eb04. For testing live data, it looks like you need an observer on it.

Comment: Huh - that example has a dependent livedata object. Your example is literally setting the live data internal field and then checking it. It should not need to be observed. But if it works ... :shrug:

Comment: Actually you are right. It doesn't work. The `getOrAwaitValue` works if the API call was done within 2 seconds so that it doesn't throw an exception. But there's still the problem where the suspend function is running async and not blocking the assertion.

Comment: I've tried to DI the dispatcher but that doesn't work too sadly. The coroutine in the view model is still not blocking the assertion call. I put a 5 sec `delay` in the coroutine and I get the exception thrown by `getOrAwaitValue` that it's waited past 2 secs and failed to get a value.

Comment: What if you `advanceUntilIdle` with the injected dispatcher? (see update)

Comment: Sadly that doesn't work. I've updated my post with what I have so far. I might have to just use `Thread.sleep` sadly.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this problem, I had to use this helper function from https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/unit-testing-livedata-and-other-common-observability-problems-bb477262eb04

```
/* Copyright 2019 Google LLC.   
   SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0 */
fun <T> LiveData<T>.getOrAwaitValue(
    time: Long = 2,
    timeUnit: TimeUnit = TimeUnit.SECONDS
): T {
    var data: T? = null
    val latch = CountDownLatch(1)
    val observer = object : Observer<T> {
        override fun onChanged(o: T?) {
            data = o
            latch.countDown()
            this@getOrAwaitValue.removeObserver(this)
        }
    }

    this.observeForever(observer)

    // Don't wait indefinitely if the LiveData is not set.
    if (!latch.await(time, timeUnit)) {
        throw TimeoutException("LiveData value was never set.")
    }

    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
    return data as T
}
```